# сидiти vs сидiть

Tags: граматика

Wiktionary shows both forms as the infinitive. And I can find examples of both in context on Reversio, but I can't seem to see a theme that defines which one to use when. Is there a grammatical rule here? Or is it a "sounds better" situation and I am still not hearing that difference? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a grammatical rule here?

The default one is with *-ти*, therefore if you search any verb then you use only this form. If we speak about any rule then you may check [the [current] standard spelling](https://files.nas.gov.ua/PublicMessages/Documents/0/2021/01/210118223223523-1428.pdf#page=153):

> § 118. Неозначена форма дієслова (інфінітив)
>
> Неозначена форма дієслова закінчується на **-ти**: *гли́бшати*, *годува́ти*, *ду́мати*, *жи́ти*, *ки́нути*, *лі́зти*, *мандрува́ти*, *нести́*, *пекти́*, *пекти́ся* (*пекти́сь*), *ревти́*, *розумі́ти*, *стоя́ти*, *ходи́ти*, *хоті́ти*.
>
> **Примітка 1.** В усному мовленні, а часом і в художньому стилі вживають також і форму інфінітива на **-ть**, коли основа дієслова закінчується на голосний: *брать*, *каза́ть*, *ки́нуть*, *терпі́ть*, *ходи́ть*.

The rule basically says: *-ти* is only one, but you can meet *-ть* in colloquial and writing styles if itʼs after any vowel.

> Or is it a "sounds better" situation

Yes, itʼs phonesthetics. ~[*vowel*]*ть* + *the next word starts with a vowel* or *-ти* + *the word with consonant*. Itʼs like English *a ~ an* or how you pronounce *the* with the next word.

Why this pair? The *и* which was the same as *і* — a «soft» vowel — sometimes changes to *ь*. So, you just remove a vowel but no the soft-status. Not only here, for compare, imperative verbs have the similar scheme: *ходи* ~ *ходь*. But not always, *кинь* cannʼt be reverted into *кини*, but the verb is «non-standard» itself. Kinda the same pattern is with *о* ~ *ø*: *робимо ~ робим*.

But just in case, if it isnʼt about any test or exam then you can just ingore but know about this thing, and use the main forms as *-ти*, *-мо* etc.